# GCC Compiler options supported for given version

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

I have an powerpc cross compiled gcc tool chain of version 3.4.3
I am getting certain error for options which are not supported by this compiler like (unrecognized command line option "-Wno-pointer-sign")
Is there a way i can print all supported compiler option for this gcc version. I dont have source code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gcc --help=warnings` to get the full list of supported `-Wsomething` options. Regarding the rest, there're `gcc --help=common`, `gcc --help=params` etc, check `gcc --help` output